# get ajax filtered url

Tags: ajax, url

for example i wanna buy laptop. so i go to www.example.com and i go to laptop section. url is : example.com/laptops
and in the filter section i choose *asus* and the url still is: example.com/laptops

i tried to record what is going on when i hit asus checkbox :

```html
action=filter&filter=2&sort=desc&count=20&menu_name=6&down_price=100&up_price=14790000&groups=&filters_specific=&color=&keyword=&exist=0&special=1
```

it sends this information to the referer.

i wanna know how to get the url that always lead me to asus laptops in that site.

Comment: onyl Get requests are  mentioned in URL....

Comment: to see post request params you have to see the xhr network tab in inspector

Comment: @RohitasBehera is there any way to change post to get using inspect or some how? :D

Comment: can you show the complete URL.... i can help you undersrtand get and post

Comment: @RohitasBehera well.. https://www.mobileabi.com/product/گوشی-موبایل/موبایل/  is the url with filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardon my arabic...when you go to the [home page](https://www.mobileabi.com) and click on the laptop(لپ-تاپ/) section ...the following URL comes

> [https://www.mobileabi.com/product/لپ-تاپ/](https://www.mobileabi.com/product/%D9%84%D9%BE-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%BE/)

also on the right side the filter appears **لپ تاپ و الترابوک**

Now from here whenever you check a product ..say acer... an ajax post request fired to the this url

> https://www.mobileabi.com/templates/user/modules/sellbasket/ajax.php

you can check it in chrome by pressing **F12>Network>XHR**

Now each of the brands are given an ID..you could find the group ID by inspect element...

```
Acer : 216
Lenovo :245
Apple: 251 and so on...
```

so for e.g. if Acer & Apple are checked in the filter..the URL post params would be **groups:216,251** so only... acer & apple laptops would be selected in the post response... you wont see any change in the URL of browser

in order to make the Post into a get Request you gotta change the ajax call at..

```
 $.ajax({
          url: "https://www.mobileabi.com/templates/user/modules/search/ajax.php",
                                data: "action=search"+
                                      "&val="+$(this).val(),
                                dataType: "html",
                                cache: false,
                                context: document.body,
                                type: "POST",
```

you have to change the  type: "POST", to  type: "GET",

similar modification needs to be done on the server side

Comment: i know! i want url to show me ONLY asus laptops or apple laptops.

Comment: the URL wont show becuase its a post request and not a get

Comment: let me know..if I need to tell something more :)

Comment: yes...you can  make the get request a post...& then update the URL...but that is too much effort  and exposing data in URL is not a good practise

Comment: i have a site that all online stores can show theyr products in my site. its like a very big store of everything! so for adding that site products to my site and make my site robot link the correct url, i need to give it exact filtered url, so apple laptops goes to apple laptops on my site!

Comment: yeah./..in that case you must make your ajax.php a Get request

Comment: i see this particular line of code is making  the post request ..  $("#input_search").keyup(function(){
                                 var sum=$("#s").val();
                                 var c=$("#c").val();                        
                                  e=$(this).attr('id');

Comment: I have suggested some basic steps for post to get conversion which will change the URL